# Is there a way to create a global service from a docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a swarm stack using a docker compose file. Is it possible to specify that my service is global, and should be run one instance on each node?

My current Docker compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  minecraft:
    external: true

services:
  bungee:
    image: bungee
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - minecraft
    ports:
      - 25565:25577
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to remove the number of replicas and set the **deploy mode** to global (see below) :

```
services:
  worker:
    image: bungee
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

You can check [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#mode)